# Why forward proxy on apache2 can't be closed?

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy

For the server installed apache2 on debian8, two import config file is as follows.
Here is the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.conf` file.

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLProxyVerify none
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
     <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyVia  block
</IfModule>
```

Here is the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` file.

```
ServerName  www.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyEngine ON     
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

The forward proxy in vps_ip is still work,why?

```
curl -x vps_ip:80 -I  yahoo.com #perform on local pc
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Why can't close forward proxy on vps?

Comment: You show two versions of the proxy.conf file in the question. One with allow and one deny. Can you clarify which version is installed and where?

Comment: I'm sorry. How careless of me,all wrong info corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProxyRequests off
```

This is the directive to not allow Forward Proxy, note that this it is off by default, so you probably have it "on" somewhere else.

Also directive entries like `<Proxy *>` make little sense unless you do want to allow forward proxying.

Comment: `ProxyRequests off` is added on all config file,it is of no use.

Comment: It was tested that  in default   forword proxy was in closed status on `Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)`,but  forword proxy was in opened status on `Server: Apache/2.4 (ubuntu16.04)` .PLease try it on some vps to check my conclusion.

Comment: if you have proxyrequests off and you can still use your server as your forward proxy there are only two possibilities. 1º you are still missing something in your config where it is allowed. 2º you are not "landing" in the server you think you are landing. Try adding a specific response header and use "curl -I" to make curl show headers and make sure you are really reaching your server.